# Unable to see widget data once I logout of sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, dashboard, sonarqube5.1

I have configured a couple of widgets on sonarqube dashboard. 
I would like these widgets to be visible to anyone who lands on my sonarqube webpage.

However once i logout of the page , The widgets display "no data".

I have set the filter of my projects to be visible to all users. How can i make the data visible to the people even though they do not sign in .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a permissions issue. If you don't have permission to "Browse" a project, then you won't see its data - even outside of the project dashboard context.

Sounds like you've set up project widgets on a global dashboard(?) and Anyone doesn't have Browse on the project(s) in question.

Comment: Hi Ann ,    
Worked on setting the browse permission to AnyOne. Thank you